# Segregate results from a file using awk or sed after matching multiple patterns

Tags: awk, pattern-matching

From one of our application logs that contains a bunch of INFO messages, and system out lines, I want to be able to extract lines that are contained within 2 patterns and then specifically get values from other lines within the resulting lines.

This is my input file

```
2019-08-16 00:38:29,171 1065142892 [http-bio-8443-exec-146] INFO aaaaa
2019-08-16 00:38:29,172 1065142893 [http-bio-8443-exec-146] INFO bbbbb
              'This is the matching pattern'
tag1: value1
tag2: value2
tag3: value3
'this is the end pattern' xxxyyyzzz

2019-08-16 00:39:29,171 1065142992 [http-bio-8443-exec-146] INFO aaaaa
2019-08-16 00:39:29,172 1065142993 [http-bio-8443-exec-146] INFO bbbbb
              'This is the matching pattern'
tag1: valuea
tag2: valueb
tag3: valuec
'this is the end pattern' xxxyyyzzzadasd

2019-08-16 00:38:29,171 1065142892 [http-bio-8443-exec-146] INFO aaaaa
2019-08-16 00:38:29,172 1065142893 [http-bio-8443-exec-146] INFO bbbbb
              'This is the matching pattern'
tag1: valuep

2019-08-16 01:38:29,171 1065153992 [http-bio-8443-exec-146] INFO aaaaa
2019-08-16 01:38:29,172 1065153993 [http-bio-8443-exec-146] INFO bbbbb
              'This is the matching pattern1'
tag1: valuexx
tag2: valueyy
tag3: valuezz
'this is the end pattern' xxxyyyzzzadasdqwerty
```

From this, I want to extract the output in the following way:

**Output:**

```
value1, value2
valuea, valueb
valuexx, valueyy
```

I have tried using the following to filter results

```
awk '/This is the matching pattern/,/This is the end pattern/' logfile
OR
awk ' /This is the matching pattern/{flag=1;next}/This is the end pattern/{flag=0}flag' logfile
OR
sed -n -e '/This is the matching pattern/,/this is the end pattern/{ /This is the matching pattern/d; /this is the end pattern/d; p; }'  logfile
```

But these bring ***tag1: valuep*** in the output which did not have a matching end pattern to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example there's no reason to test for `This is the matching pattern`, just the end regexp:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=": "; OFS=", " }
{ f[$1] = $2 }
/this is the end pattern/ {
    print f["tag1"], f["tag2"]
    delete f
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
value1, value2
valuea, valueb
valuexx, valueyy
```